# jQuery Mobile one menu (only one HTML code)

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, navigation

The way I do a menu in jQuery Mobile (JQM) now is like this: for each page (`data-role="page"`) I create a navigation (`data-role="navbar"`), so there's repetition, which goes against the Don't Repeat Yourself principle.

Is there a way to create only one menu and it will be shown across all pages?

Answer (score 1):

Create a page that is your menu, then just link to the "menu page" from all the other pages. I would either add the code for the "menu page" to each document in the site or write some JS code that dynamically injects the "menu page" into the DOM (only once per full-page-load).

```
<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="content">
            <a data-role="button" href="#menu">Menu</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="menu">
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                ...
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

This method is nice because it takes no custom coding and you can animate the in/out animations of the menu like any other page. And now that jQuery Mobile 1.1.0+ detects and serves transitions by device capability this is even better to use.

You can also add the menu page via JS like so:

```
//wait for the DOM.ready event
$(function () {
    $('body').append('\
        <div data-role="page" id="menu">\
            <div data-role="content">\
                <ul data-role="listview">\
                    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>\
                    ...\
                </ul>\
            </div>\
        </div>');
});
```

Notice that I have escaped the end-lines so this does not throw an error.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Your solution (here is on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JHbBm/) has a menu as a page and is not visible on other pages, you have to first navigate to it, which is wrong.
And I doubt your javascript solution would work as JQM does some magic on HTML before it becomes a menu (adding classes and whatnot).